# Activation link web api using angular.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a website using angular.js and my backend is using asp.net web api.  When a new user register a e-mail is send with an activation link and a token inside it like this :

localhost:51426/#/activation?userid=test&code=FCuuf27NzVvmwp2Ksd7IDt83C2XZmZ2paCrZPBLgr9qR8xCaXELvqKCsWlg4uiokb07XK5sQ+2BazHN1+2B74q14grkQY2OHDAVeWlin5GE8ugkyw+2BJFFzd3Q2YiVuMxkmkO6OFdhIyfzUQMV8NPipME+2FST1pa0OuQs90kRUNR5kTkPlGQYKflDOMQvDGV84fZIw

When the user click the link I have an angular controller that basically just take the parameter and call the good method inside the web.api like this :

return $http.post(baseUrl + 'api/v1/account/confirmAccount?userId=' + userId + '&code=' + code);

The problem it seems all the + are replace by space in the server side so when I try to validate the token in my web api it doesn't work.

Not sure to understand why the + it's replace by space and how to avoid this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try passing the url parameters to the config and not just in the url? `$http.post(baseUrl + 'api/v1/account/confirmAccount', null, {userId: myUserId, code: myCode});` Note that the second parameter is the post content which is null in your case as i can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in query strings + characters [are replaced by spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string):

> URL Encoding:
>
> The HTML specifies the following transformation:
>
> - SPACE is encoded as '+' or "%20" [9]

What you could do is replace the space characters with + on the server:

`string newCode=code.Replace(' ','+')`

Comment: Yes, I was thinking so, I was just hoping to find a better behavior but if it's impossible I will go this way.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to build the string first and eliminate the + altogether.